# VSCode Integrated terminal pointing to different python version

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to get a Python Venv setup and configured to use VSCode's integrated terminal and Code Runner. However, both seem to be using the wrong Python version.
It almost seems like it's using a completely different environment.
See screenshot, the above is my regular terminal, and the one below is VSCode's integrated terminal.

[image]

The terminal is configured to use `/bin/bash` and .py files to run with `$pythonPath -u $fullFileName`.
The selected interpreter is `~/venv/bin/python3.11`
I've also already tried `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false` to prevent `source /home/wsiz01/venv/bin/activate` although this didn't make a difference.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be going on here?

Comment: Try in *Terminal>Integrated>Env: Enable Persistent Sessions* to toggle this option off and restarting VSCode, to clear the PATH cache. If it works, you may toggle the option back on.

Comment: I've tried turning off _Terminal>Integrated>Env: Enable Persistent Sessions_ and restarting VSCode, also tried rebooting the device. Sadly there are no changes in my findings.

Comment: Do you have both versions of Python installed? Try to uninstall or at least to rename the folder of the old one, and see whether you get an error message (and which one). See also [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497210/vscode-extensions-code-runner-and-python-previewer-do-not-use-the-interpreter-i).

Comment: 1st part of the screenshot shows venv isn't activated, 2nd part shows it is. Not sure what your goal here is - to not activate venv in VSCode Terminal? This needs clarity and more details IMO.

Comment: I haven't installed python3.10 manually and can't find it, python3.11 was installed manually.

Comment: > "I've also already tried "python.terminal.activateEnvironment": false to prevent source /home/wsiz01/venv/bin/activate although this didn't make a difference."

I already tried not activating the venv in vscode, the goal is to use the python3.11 venv, this is now solved (after my solution it uses the selected interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

After doing more digging I've found that this was a problem with my vscode package.

I've found the answer here: https://github.com/flathub/com.visualstudio.code#use-host-shell-in-the-integrated-terminal

I'm still not sure where python3.10 came from but, by adding the below to settings.json the integrated shell was correctly set to my host shell.

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash flathub",
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
    "bash flathub": {
        "path": "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn",
        "args": [
            "--host",
            "--env=TERM=xterm-256color",
            "bash"
        ],
        "icon": "terminal-bash",
        "overrideName": true
    }
}
```